# Selecting/transforming table element with xsl 3.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am having a problem selecting an HTML table within an XML document with the XSL stylesheet that transforms the page.

I am trying to select the table with class="table factbook".  The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
<document>

    <headcode></headcode> <!-- before closing head tag -->
    <bodycode></bodycode> <!-- after opening body tag -->
    <footcode></footcode> <!-- before closing body tag -->


        <h4>University of Georgia Fact Books</h4>
        <table class="table factbook">
            <caption>Table becomes a bunch of divs</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>2016</h3>
                        <a href="/_resources/files/factbook/FactBook2016.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 167px; border: solid 1px #272727;" src="/_resources/files/factbook/2016FB_Cover_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>
                    <td>
                        <h3>2015</h3>
                        <a href="/_resources/files/factbook/FactBook2015.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 167px; border: solid 1px #272727;" src="/_resources/files/factbook/2015FB-Cover_thumb.png" alt="" /></a></td>
                    <td>
                        <h3>2014</h3>
                        <a href="/_resources/files/factbook/FactBook2014.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 167px; border: solid 1px #272727;" src="/_resources/files/factbook/2014FB-Cover_thumb.png" alt="" /></a></td>
                    <td>
                        <h3>2013</h3>
                        <a href="/_resources/files/factbook/FactBook2013.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 167px; border: solid 1px #272727;" src="http://69.39.227.24/_resources/files/factbook/2013FB-Cover_thumb.png" alt="" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</document>
```

The XSL looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- factbook transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="//table[@class='table factbook']">
        <xsl:for-each select="tbody/tr/td">
            <div class="grid">
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/document">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML></xsl:text>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="headcode/node()"/>
            </head>
            <body>          
                <xsl:apply-templates select="bodycode/node()"/>
                <div class="wrap" role="document">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="container">
                            <xsl:call-template name="page-content"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="footcode/node()"/> <!-- pcf -->    
            </body>
        </html> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="page-content">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/document">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the result you want and the result or error you currently get. I don't see how the XSLT with only `<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0">` and not declaring the XSLT namespace can be parsed or even executed at all.

Comment: I added the namespace and the expected result at the end.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. The input has no closing tag for the root element and the used entity references are not declared. So please explain in details how you parse and feed that input to which XSLT processor.

Comment: The usual problem with templates not matching are namespaces so perhaps `match="/document/table[@class='table factbook']"` does not match as the HTML parser you use to parse the input puts its elements into a namespace, probably the XHTML namespace if it is an HTML parser. So in that case you would need to make sure you use `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the root element of the stylesheet or at least on the templates where you want to match HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I did post the complete XSL and XML so that you could see.  I eventually figured out that I used <xsl:copy-of instead of <xsl:apply-templates.